# I cant delete sqlite data from ListView after calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I cant delete sqlite data from ListView after calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
I deleted one Draft item from my list view item and sqlite table,i cheched with facebook stetho .that item deleted successfully ,but showing fragment until fragment calling onCreateView
my code here:

```
public void confirmRemove(final Context context, final int id) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Confirm")
            .setMessage("Do you really want to remove this draft?")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    ordersDB = new OrdersDB(context);
                    ArrayList<Order> mOrders = ordersDB.getOrders("Draft", 0);
                    ordersDB.delete(id);
                    mOrders.remove(0);
                    updateFragment1ListView();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Item removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
}

 public static void updateFragment1ListView() {
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


  public int delete(long id) {
    this.open();
    int ret = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    this.close();
    return ret;
}
```

Delete success from database but showing when fragment reload
I add zero (0) as index

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry...i edited my question

Comment: I suggest you use a Cusor adapter and delete objects from the database.

Comment: Delete success from database but showing when fragment reload

Comment: Use a CursorAdapter instead of an ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You are just deleting local copy of Order object by this code!

```
ordersDB = new OrdersDB(context);
ArrayList<Order> mOrders = ordersDB.getOrders("Draft", 0);
ordersDB.delete(id);
mOrders.remove(0);
```

You need to delete that item from the global source which is using by your adapter, and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method to get desired result.